# Xamarin.Forms dependecy injection for native accessibility features

Tags: xamarin, dependency-injection, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, accessibility

I would like to know if it was possible to perform dependency injection for native platforms accessibility features, as Automation Properties is not good enough.

By this, I mean that I would like to add hints/descriptions and other native accessibility features to my Xamarin. Forms view items such as entries or labels. If it isn't possible or this is a silly way of doing it, is there another way to apply native accessibility?

Pointing me in the right direction or a small example would be very helpful :D Thank you

Comment: Can you check thease

Comment: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/XamarinForms-101-Accessibility-using-Automation-Properties

Comment: https://www.xamarinhelp.com/accessibility-support-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Yeah as mentioned Automation Properties doesn't quite do what I want

Comment: Check this link(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/dependency-injection) may help you.